Why can't I connect to my EC2 instance through AWS CloudFront?
I'm moving a WordPress site onto AWS. To do this, I've set up the following architecture:

A single EC2 instance held in a target group with a database and WordPress installed on it.
An Elastic Load Balancer pointing at that target group.
A CloudFront distribution that's using the Elastic Load Balancer as an origin.

Because this is a development version of the site, I can't alter the DNS records to point at the IP address for any parts of my architecture. I'm editing my hosts file to point at the architecture to get around this.
I have control over the DNS records, so I've been able to get certificates from Amazon Certificate Manager, which I've put on CloudFront and the Elastic Load Balancer. My EC2 instance has a self-signed certificate that I've trusted in my Root store.
When I point to my CloudFront distribution's IP, which I found by trace routing the address, I get the following:

When I point at the public IP of the EC2 instance I get sent straight to the site with no issue. When I point at the Elastic Load Balancer, I get through to the site, but have mixed content warnings:

I'm adding this in case it hints at what's going wrong, but I'm not worried about fixing it for now.
I've already been through my architecture and ensured all the security groups are setup to allow traffic. I've added certificates to CloudFront and the Elastic Load Balancer.
What am I doing wrong, how can I get through the CloudFront distribution to my EC2 WordPress origin?

I resolved this issue by editing the General Settings of my CloudFront distribution and redeploying. I didn't have a CNAME record attached to my CloudFront distribution with my site's name on it.
I changed this:

Redeployed my distribution, and now I can access my site fine. Albeit with the same mixed content issues!
